# PC is not powering on

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I put my windows PC into sleep mode and came back hours later to see it completely powered off. Pressing the power button does absolutely nothing. Here's what I've tried:

- I/O switch set to I
- verified all internal wires are plugged in
- paperclip PSU test (it worked)
- shorting the powerbtn pins (didn't work)
- verified both the external power wire and the power strip work

I've had this skytech archangel PC since 2017, and I did nothing to cause this, so what could be happening?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: something important may have died (if there's really absolutely no signs of life, it's most likely the motherboard) - however: disconnect everything unimportant (hard drives etc), remove and re-attach power cables to the motherboard. Remove and reseat RAM, and if you can, remove and reseat CPU (you may want thermal paste on hand, after 6 years you'll need to clean and re-apply thermal paste). Then try again. All you want attached is power to the motherboard, RAM, CPU, Graphics card if your CPU doesn't include integrated graphics

Comment: ^^^ if it powers on, then re-attach things one by one (with the power off of course) powering on after each new device is attached

Comment: Hey, so I just woke up and read these. As sort of a cope, I pressed the power button and it turned on. What in tarnation could have been causing it to stay powered off for 4 days?